# Solana recovery from wrong transfer

Tags: transfer, solana-pay

Unfortunately I transferred  mistakenly to wrong wallet.
I was trying to find solona support to report about this issue,is anybody can suggest is there way to recover or I would  be greatful if someone can suggest how to reach Solana customer support, where i can communicate with Solona main net/Production Team.

PS:I have tried through discord and telegram but no luck.

Thankyou in advance!

Answer (score 4):

The whole point of blockchain is **not** to provide option that you are asking for. Transaction can not be reverted and nobody (even solana team) can help you about it. The only way to recover your money is to find the owner and ask the owner to send you back your sol, but good luck with that.